# How to check for a drive's existence in Debian Linux

Tags: linux, bash, sata

I have a Debian Linux server with two eSATA drives attached to it (NTFS, bleh). They are currently mounted fine and have proper fstab entries setup (using UUID, not /dev locations).

I've come to the conclusion that I need to add 'noauto' mount options so that they aren't mounted when the server boots (to prevent the server from hanging when they aren't present. I do plan on taking them on an occasional excursion).

However, how should I setup an init script to mount them once the system has booted? I could do a `mount /mount/location`, but I would prefer to check for their existence before doing that (to prevent an error from being thrown). Also, do I just need to throw this script into the `/etc/init.d/` directory for it to work? (I'm fairly new to Debian)

Comment: Have a look at AutoFS >> http://wiki.debian.org/AutoFs

Comment: This question is off-topic on Stack Overflow, it's more of a system usage question than a programming question. The topic is fairly well covered at [Super User](http://superuser.com/) and [Unix Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). You're looking for [Udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev), a tool to perform an action when a device is detected. Start with [Automatizing the sequence of mounting commands](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11807); other udev questions may be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`blkid` shows a list of block devices.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the information. AutoFS and Udev are the proper things to research to come up with a solution to this problem of mine.

Also, the `blkid` command does properly show a list of block devices even if they are not mounted. Extrapolating on this, here's an (error prone) rudimentary script for handling mounting block devices which doesn't rely on AutoFS and Udev (just a temporary solution):

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
define('DRIVE1',    '7E088E5B088E11F7');
define('DRIVE2',    '4A841A75841A63AB');
$devices = `/sbin/blkid`;

if (strpos($devices, DRIVE1) !== FALSE) {
    $output = `mount /storage/drive1`;
    $output = trim($output);
    echo "Mounting /storage/drive1... $output\n";
} else {
    echo "Not Mounting: /storage/drive1\n";
}
if (strpos($devices, DRIVE2) !== FALSE) {
    $output = `mount /storage/drive2`;
    $output = trim($output);
    echo "Mounting /storage/drive2... $output\n";
} else {
    echo "Not Mounting: /storage/drive2\n";
}
```